Detecting closure of externally launched Tizen application with tizen.application.launchAppControl?
Hello I am developing a Tizen application that integrates with external functionalities, such as bluetooth music, using tizen.application.launchAppControl. I need to monitor the lifecycle of the launched application to detect when it is closed or terminated.

I want to implement this detection mechanism within my Tizen
application using appropriate APIs or event listeners.
The goal is to perform specific actions or updates in my application when the launched external application is no longer running.

